# Rails association with session login and a user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, associations

I have setup a an association with a user and events. I have the association setup correctly and have tested it in my rails console that using user = User.find(1) user.events, brings up my associated events. My question comes into play with authentication. I have a login that right now when it signs in it goes directly to the main page and shows all open events(like an admin page):

Session Controller:

```
 def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:name], params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to events_url
    else
        redirect_to login_url, :alert => "Invalid user/password combination"
    end
  end
```

I want to be able to create a login and associate it with all events for that person. For example, employee logs in with initials JM, I want all events open with that persons initials to show up in their que. Here are some other pieces of my application that I think might be applicable.

```
   class EventsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.order("events.initials ASC")
    @archived = CompleteEvent.order("complete_events.created_at ASC")


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @events }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/new
  # GET /events/new.json
  def new
    @event = Event.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /events/1
  # PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      @complete = CompleteEvent.new(:initials => @event.initials, :name => @event.name, :event_name => @event.event_name, :complete => @event.complete, :event_description => @event.event_description, :comment => @event.comment)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
        if @event.complete == true
              @complete
              @complete.save
              @event.destroy
          format.html { redirect_to :controller => :events, :action => :index}
          format.json { head :no_content }
            elsif @event.complete == false          
          format.html { redirect_to :controller => :events, :action => :index}
          format.json { head :no_content }
            end
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: You are using your own authentication here? I know that with devise you have the method current_user available, so you could show all events belonging to that user, is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do. I want the current_user to be associated with the initials of each event and only show those. I will look at devise.